# WebDriver Firefox driver not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class GoogleSuggest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // The Firefox driver supports javascript 
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // Go to the Google Suggest home page
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");

        // Enter the query string "Cheese"
        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        query.sendKeys("Cheese");

        // Sleep until the div we want is visible or 5 seconds is over
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_e"));

            // If results have been returned, the results are displayed in a drop down.
            if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
              break;
            }
        }

        // And now list the suggestions
        List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='gssb_a gbqfsf']"));

        for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions) {
            System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
        }

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
419587346786    addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
1419587346788   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346788   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346789   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1419587346793   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1419587346793   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346793   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346793   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60} installed in winreg-app-global
1419587346803   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon winreg-app-global:{D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60} visible
1419587346803   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346803   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346819   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1419587346819   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1419587346824   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1419587346833   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1419587346833   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1419587346834   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1419587346834   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1419587347704   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1419587347734   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1419587347735   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1419587347735   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1419587347735   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1419587347735   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1419587347736   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1419587347736   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1419587347738   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1419587348285   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1419587348285   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
1419587348285   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1419587348287   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
1419587348764   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1419587348765   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1419587348767   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1419587348768   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60} to C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\SystemCore
1419587348768   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1419587348769   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1419587348769   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1419587348770   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\391071\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous5788014813400759008webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1419587348770   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\391071\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous5788014813400759008webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1419587348770   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1419587348787   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1419587348790   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1419587348790   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1419587348791   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1419587348791   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
1419587350198   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.example.GoogleSuggest.main(GoogleSuggest.java:14)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
419587346786    addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
1419587346788   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346788   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346789   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1419587346793   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1419587346793   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346793   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346793   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60} installed in winreg-app-global
1419587346803   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon winreg-app-global:{D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60} visible
1419587346803   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346803   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346819   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1419587346819   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1419587346824   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1419587346833   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1419587346833   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1419587346834   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1419587346834   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1419587347704   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1419587347734   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1419587347735   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1419587347735   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1419587347735   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1419587347735   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1419587347736   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1419587347736   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1419587347738   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1419587348285   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1419587348285   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
1419587348285   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1419587348287   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
1419587348764   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1419587348765   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1419587348767   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1419587348768   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60} to C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\SystemCore
1419587348768   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1419587348769   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1419587348769   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1419587348770   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\391071\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous5788014813400759008webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1419587348770   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\391071\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous5788014813400759008webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1419587348770   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1419587348787   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1419587348790   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1419587348790   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1419587348791   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1419587348791   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
1419587350198   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>

Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'
System info: host: 'PC217330', ip: '10.230.165.168', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.example.GoogleSuggest.main(GoogleSuggest.java:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
419587346786    addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
1419587346788   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346788   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346789   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1419587346793   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1419587346793   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346793   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346793   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60} installed in winreg-app-global
1419587346803   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon winreg-app-global:{D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60} visible
1419587346803   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346803   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1419587346819   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1419587346819   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1419587346824   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1419587346833   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1419587346833   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1419587346834   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1419587346834   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1419587347704   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1419587347734   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1419587347735   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1419587347735   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1419587347735   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1419587347735   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1419587347736   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1419587347736   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1419587347738   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1419587348285   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1419587348285   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
1419587348285   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1419587348287   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
1419587348764   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1419587348765   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1419587348767   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1419587348768   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60} to C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\SystemCore
1419587348768   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1419587348769   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1419587348769   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1419587348770   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\391071\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous5788014813400759008webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1419587348770   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\391071\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous5788014813400759008webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1419587348770   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1419587348787   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1419587348790   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1419587348790   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1419587348791   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1419587348791   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
1419587350198   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: What is your selenium version? do you using latest?

Answer (score 5):

*Here are some solutions to your problem, Please try them .*

**1. Upgrade to "selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0" and "selenium-java-2.44.0" .**

***2 Try below steps***

**A)Un-install latest firefox.**

**B)Install 3.22 version of Firefox.**

**C)Run your selenium program.**

[Here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/) is the Download link for various FF versions(Make sure you download 'esr' version)

**3. Recommend you turn off automatic updates on FF when youre do your testing.**

Below are some of the reported Issue between FF and Selenium versions i found

*Selenium version:2.42 & FF 29*

*Selenium 2.41.0 & FF 32.0*

*Selenium WebDriver version: 2.42. & FF 32.0*

*Selenium 2.43.1 & FF 31.1.1*

*Selenium v2.43 & FF 27*

selenium-firefox-driver 2.44 & FF 34.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest Selenium version, which currently is 2.45.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.45.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Do that for all your selenium related dependencies. You can always check the latest versions [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium).