# Not able to run the selenium code in Mozilla Firefox Browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver

During running the script from FireFox Browser getting below error on page, please advice how to proceed.

FireFox Version - 32.0.3
Eclipse Juno version 1
Selenium 2.38 Jar
Window 8  Version

```
Error message throwing in the console is :
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
eferredSave.extensions.json DEBUG   Starting write
1423547733710   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1423547733710   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1423547733764   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1423547733764   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
1423547733764   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1423547733767   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
1423547734167   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1423547734168   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1423547734169   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1423547734170   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1423547734170   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1423547734171   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1423547734171   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1423547734173   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\PREMAN~1.S\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous1824976243334194970webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1423547734173   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\PREMAN~1.S\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous1824976243334194970webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1423547734173   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1423547734195   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1423547734199   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1423547734199   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1423547734205   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 7.2.15747.10003
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
console.error: skype_ff_extension: 
  DEPRECATED: The widget module is deprecated.  Please consider using the sdk/ui module instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 114, in startup/<
    run(options);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 170, in run
    let program = main(options.loader, options.main);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 645, in main
    return loader.load(loader, module).exports;
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
    result = load(loader, module);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 299, in load
    evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 262, in evaluate
    : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
  File "resource://skype_ff_extension-at-jetpack/skype_ff_extension/lib/main.js", line 14, in null
    var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 619, in require
    freeze(load(loader, module));
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
    result = load(loader, module);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 299, in load
    evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 262, in evaluate
    : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js", line 60, in null
    "The widget module is deprecated.  " +
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/util/deprecate.js", line 18, in deprecateUsage
    let stack = get().slice(2);

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at Demo.SetupTest(Demo.java:25)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:19)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
eferredSave.extensions.json DEBUG   Starting write
1423547733710   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1423547733710   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1423547733764   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1423547733764   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
1423547733764   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1423547733767   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
1423547734167   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1423547734168   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1423547734169   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1423547734170   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1423547734170   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1423547734171   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1423547734171   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1423547734173   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\PREMAN~1.S\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous1824976243334194970webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1423547734173   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\PREMAN~1.S\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous1824976243334194970webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1423547734173   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1423547734195   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1423547734199   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1423547734199   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1423547734205   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 7.2.15747.10003
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
console.error: skype_ff_extension: 
  DEPRECATED: The widget module is deprecated.  Please consider using the sdk/ui module instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 114, in startup/<
    run(options);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 170, in run
    let program = main(options.loader, options.main);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 645, in main
    return loader.load(loader, module).exports;
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
    result = load(loader, module);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 299, in load
    evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 262, in evaluate
    : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
  File "resource://skype_ff_extension-at-jetpack/skype_ff_extension/lib/main.js", line 14, in null
    var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 619, in require
    freeze(load(loader, module));
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
    result = load(loader, module);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 299, in load
    evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 262, in evaluate
    : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js", line 60, in null
    "The widget module is deprecated.  " +
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/util/deprecate.js", line 18, in deprecateUsage
    let stack = get().slice(2);

Build info: version: '2.38.0', revision: 'bd32d4e', time: '2013-12-05 16:16:40'
System info: host: 'EXIND3917', ip: '10.90.3.134', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_29'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
    at Demo.SetupTest(Demo.java:25)
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:19)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
eferredSave.extensions.json DEBUG   Starting write
1423547733710   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1423547733710   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1423547733764   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1423547733764   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
1423547733764   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1423547733767   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
1423547734167   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1423547734168   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1423547734169   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1423547734170   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1423547734170   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1423547734171   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1423547734171   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1423547734173   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\PREMAN~1.S\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous1824976243334194970webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1423547734173   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\PREMAN~1.S\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous1824976243334194970webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1423547734173   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1423547734195   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1423547734199   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1423547734199   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A}.xpi
1423547734205   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} version 7.2.15747.10003
*** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
console.error: skype_ff_extension: 
  DEPRECATED: The widget module is deprecated.  Please consider using the sdk/ui module instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 114, in startup/<
    run(options);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js", line 170, in run
    let program = main(options.loader, options.main);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 645, in main
    return loader.load(loader, module).exports;
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
    result = load(loader, module);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 299, in load
    evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 262, in evaluate
    : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
  File "resource://skype_ff_extension-at-jetpack/skype_ff_extension/lib/main.js", line 14, in null
    var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 619, in require
    freeze(load(loader, module));
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js", line 129, in CuddlefishLoader/options<.load
    result = load(loader, module);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 299, in load
    evaluate(sandbox, module.uri);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js", line 262, in evaluate
    : loadSubScript(uri, sandbox, encoding);
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js", line 60, in null
    "The widget module is deprecated.  " +
  File "resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/util/deprecate.js", line 18, in deprecateUsage
    let stack = get().slice(2);

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
```

Please advice where i am going wrong ?

Comment: Please update to selenium 2.43 or above. If still happens then can you please check by clearing all instances of firefox on system and then execute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebDriver Firefox driver not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655628/webdriver-firefox-driver-not-working)

Comment: You can look into this link -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/widget

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using updated Selenium Jar file. Also close all the instances of FF and clear your %temp% folder.

Comment: Mr Shah ji, After doing all specified steps, still facing the same issue, It invoking the browser but not going next script, connect pool issue throwing on page, if i downgrade my FF browser, whether it will solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, Try downgrading it. Also try to install it in default location.Also make sure that you do not have malware in your system which is getting installed as FF plugin. It might be disturbing your execution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try  to  update selenium  in your POM.XML

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.40.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 1.x co-creator here. Choose highest number for Selenium dependency from http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.seleniumhq.selenium%22%20AND%20a%3A%22selenium-server%22.  Right now that's 2.44. Could be

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to revert to Firefox 34.0b11
It is the latest version that works with Selenium WebDriver 2.43.1

1) From control panel uninstall Firefox

2) Manually Delete the Firefox directory from Program Files (x86)  *** IMPORTANT ***

3) Install FireFox from the link below with Custom Instalation Settings and Uncheck the option for Silent Updates

This should prevent FireFox from updating itself to the next version which kills WebDriver. It has something to do with FunnelCake32, though I don't know exactly what breaks.

http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/34.0b11/win32/